# Single click edit cell

Tags: excel, vba

Im looking to see if i can get a function within my project where when you click a cell it goes straight to edit mode, rather than having to double click the cell, i know that F2 does this but id rather it be done when the user clicks the cell and its into edit mode without having to do anything else other than clicking the cell.

There are two cells i need this to be applied too, G3 and G4.

Can you help?

Iv tried recording a macro but to no avail.

Comment: If you put the code from [this old question](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/macro-to-execute-f2-function-key.37041/) (aka `SendKeys "{F2}"` in your [Worksheet_Selectionchange event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange), that should do it. Probably should test if the target intersects with your G3/G4 though.

Comment: Thanks for this, im a bit new to VBA, how would i write the code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You double click on the applicable Sheet in the Project navigator:

[image]

And paste in the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim trigger As Range
    Set trigger = Range("G3:G4,A1:A2")
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, trigger) Is Nothing Then SendKeys "{F2}"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for this, this works perfectly, would i be correct in saying that i would just need to add more If Target.Address = to apply this to other cells? Thanks again mate really appreciate your time and knowledge

Comment: I changed the code so that it's easier to add several areas in the "trigger" range.

Comment: @John Or you could use: `Select Case Target.Address(0, 0): Case "G3", "G4" ' add as many 
 needed: SendKeys "{F2}": End Select`. I prefer tnavidi's improvement though.